# What does the symbol "!" mean?

Tags: r

```
all_trips_v2 <- all_trips[!(all_trips$start_station_name == "HQ QR" | all_trips$ride_length<0),]
```

What does `!` do in this situation? Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Hi! It means "differnt to" or "not". In your case, you are deleting rows that have "HQ QR" for `$start_station_name` or `$ride_length` lower than 0.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation ! indicates logical negation (NOT). To get help use:

```
?`!`
```

In your example select rows that does not have value `start_station_name` equal to `HQ HR` or negative ride length

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the symbol `!` is the same as NOT. That is, in your example

```
all_trips[!(all_trips$start_station_name == "HQ QR" | all_trips$ride_length<0),]
```

what you are doing can be explained in two steps:

1. In `(all_trips$start_station_name == "HQ QR" | all_trips$ride_length<0)`, you want to know if the elements of the column *start_station_name* are equal to "HQ QR" OR if the elements of the column *ride_length* are smaller than 0.
2. By doing `all_trips[!(all_trips$start_station_name == "HQ QR" | all_trips$ride_length<0),]`, you are subsetting the rows in **all_trips** dataframe that DO NOT satisfy the previous conditions.

Hope this helps!